# Can't connect to nginx server from public IP Address

Tags: linux, nginx, tcp, connection

Hi I have a nginx server running on a linux machine. I can connect it to from localhost using `curl -v http://localhost:8080` fine. But can't connect it to using `curl -v http://<machine-ip>:8080`, or from browsers in some other machine.

The config file is

```
server {
        listen 8080;
        listen [::]:8080;

        root /var/www/html;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
    }
```

Port 8080 is being listened to on IPv4 and IPv6, as `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep nginx` gives

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      123495/nginx: maste
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      123495/nginx: maste
```

The firewall is down, as doing `sudo ufw status` tell `status: inactive`. 
I have looked at a lot of answers on various stack exchange sites, but can't figure out the issue. Would appreciate any help. TIA.

Comment: Is the other machine on the same network or behind a router?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was that the port was not open from the Azure side. Follow this to allow incoming traffic on port 8080 as described [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nsg-quickstart-portal), reboot the machine and it works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Since your firewall is disabled, check the nginx log first. Default nginx log can be found here-

> vi /var/log/nginx/error.log
>
> vi /var/log/nginx/access.log

If any error is logged then google that for a solution.
If nothing in those log files, try reloading or restating the nginx service.

> sudo systemctl reload nginx
>
> sudo systemctl restart nginx

Comment: Hi @Prithwi, no error is logged. ``reload nginx`` and ``restart nginx`` doesn't seem to work